# Flux V2 not pushing new image version to git repo

Tags: github, kubernetes, fluxcd

I've upgrade from Flux V1 to V2. It all went fairly smooth but I can't seem to get the `ImageUpdateAutomation` to work. Flux knows I have images to update but it doesn't change the container image in the `deployment.yaml` manifest and commit the changes to Github. I have no errors in my logs so I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to do next.

I have an file structure that looks something like this:

```
├── README.md
├── staging
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   ├── automation.yaml
│   │   └── service.yaml
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   ├── automation.yaml
│   │   └── service.yaml
│   ├── flux-system
│   │   ├── gotk-components.yaml
│   │   ├── gotk-sync.yaml
│   │   └── kustomization.yaml
│   ├── image_update_automation.yaml
```

My `staging/api/automation.yaml` is pretty strait-forward:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: image.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: ImageRepository
metadata:
  name: api
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  image: xxx/api
  interval: 1m0s
  secretRef:
    name: dockerhub

---
apiVersion: image.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: ImagePolicy
metadata:
  name: api
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  imageRepositoryRef:
    name: api
  policy:
    semver:
      range: ">=1.0.0"
```

My `staging/image_update_automation.yaml` looks something like this:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: image.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: ImageUpdateAutomation
metadata:
  name: flux-system
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  git:
    checkout:
      ref:
        branch: master
    commit:
      author:
        email: fluxcdbot@users.noreply.github.com
        name: fluxcdbot
      messageTemplate: '{{range .Updated.Images}}{{println .}}{{end}}'
    push:
      branch: master
  interval: 1m0s
  sourceRef:
    kind: GitRepository
    name: flux-system
  update:
    path: ./staging
    strategy: Setters
```

Everything seems to be ok here:

```sh
❯ flux get image repository
NAME    READY   MESSAGE                         LAST SCAN                   SUSPENDED
api True    successful scan, found 23 tags  2021-07-28T17:11:02-06:00   False
app True    successful scan, found 18 tags  2021-07-28T17:11:02-06:00   False

❯ flux get image policy
NAME    READY   MESSAGE                                                             LATEST IMAGE
api True    Latest image tag for 'xxx/api' resolved to: 1.0.1   xxx/api:1.0.1
app True    Latest image tag for 'xxx/app' resolved to: 3.2.1   xxx/app:3.2.1
```

As you can see from the policy output the `LATEST IMAGE` api is 1.0.1, however when I view the current version of my app and api they have not been updated.

```sh
kubectl get deployment api -n xxx -o json | jq '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image'
"xxx/api:0.1.5"
```

Any advice on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: In my case flux wasn't seeing that there was a new image in our docker registry. This was fixed by restarting flux-memcached.

Answer (score 4):

My issue was that I didn't add the comment after my image declaration in my deployment yaml. [More details](https://fluxcd.io/docs/guides/image-update/#configure-image-updates). Honestly, I'm surprised this is not [Annotation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/) instead of a comment.

```yaml
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: docker.io/xxx/api:0.1.5 # {"$imagepolicy": "flux-system:api"}
```

Comment: Even though i add # {"$imagepolicy": "flux-system:policy_name"} my app version isn't updated. How can i do so.